# JWT with RS256 won't accept private key

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, rsa

I am trying to use 'jsonwebtoken' to create a JWT with RS256. I have created the keys with this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -f <filename>
```

The output for the private key looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,3EA25EB113F5940340B4995D7B29B4F7

bQ4mTHOuQgGobjCKwfgOAml1BIa8Qs7VMuGTRYDyXFCNjx+5gdz687z1GdwEQlFu
GYbD15...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I read in the private key with 'fs' and pass it to jsonwebtoken with:

```
jwt.sign(myData, privateKey, options)
```

However, I am getting this error every time:

```
Error: secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256
```

I have looked it up and others with the same issue have solved it by putting it in the format that I have. It seems to be in the correct format to me, but jsonwebtoken refuses to encrypt it.

I tried remove the 2 header lines (Proc-Type and DEK-Info) but that doesn't help at all. Why is it claiming that my key is incorrect? How do I create the correct key for it if this is not it?

Comment: The private key is encrypted. Presumably the library does not support encrypted keys. Try using the unencrypted key.

Comment: The only files generated were the private key (the one shown here) and the public key. Sorry, I am a bit ignorant on this, but what/where would the unencrypted key be?

Comment: When generating the key, you (presumably) entered a password so that the private key was encrypted. If you do not enter this password or add `-N ""` to your statement, the key will not be encrypted. Alternatively, an existing encrypted key can be decrypted, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112409/9014097).

Comment: Yes, I did enter a password. I tried using this password. It does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by *... I tried using this password. It does not work...* When signing? As I said, the library probably does not support encrypted keys. You have to decrypt the key.

Comment: You can also import the encrypted key at runtime, but you will need the *crypto* module from NodeJS. The required function is [`crypto.createPrivateKey()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreateprivatekeykey).

Comment: I used a password to generate the key. I know the password. The private key file was generated. When I use the password (replacing 'privateKey' with 'myPassword') I am getting the same error.

Comment: Try changing the password with `ssh-keygen -p -P <old password> -N <new password> -m PEM -f <path to enc key>`. Works for me. With `-N ""` no new password is applied and the key is unencrypted.

Comment: Still no good. I tried it out on https://jwt.io/, When I enter the private key (encrypted) it is saying "Invalid Token". I have no idea why the token is invalid.

Comment: AFAIK, jwt.io does not support encrypted RSA keys. The password may be incorrect. Try to generate a new key.

Comment: *When I enter the private key (encrypted) it is saying "Invalid Token"* - 1. to verify a token, you need the public key, not the private key. 2. if you use your encrypted private key and don't enter the password anywhere (because there's no way to do it), the key is useless anyway 3. I tried and see "Invalid signature" which just means that the signature can't be verified (for the reasons mentioned before), it does not mean that your token is actually wrong. Please try to generate a key pair that is not encrypted as mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: Contrary to my first assumption, *jsonwebtoken* does after all support the import of encrypted keys (so that `crypto.createPrivateKey()` does not have to be used *explicitly*), please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of the [*jsonwebtoken*](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) library, encrypted keys are also supported, see sec. [*Usage*](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken?tab=readme-ov-file#usage):

> In case of a private key with passphrase an object { key, passphrase }
> can be used (based on crypto documentation), in this case be sure you
> pass the algorithm option.

Below you will find a sample code. The encrypted key was generated with your *ssh-keygen* statement (with the password *whatever*):

```js
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

//
// Signing
//

var pkcs1PemEncrypted = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,1163F6773A42B5DFDCF62BC633E69B22
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`;

var payload = {
    sub: '1234567890',
    name: 'John Doe',
    admin: true,
    iat: 1516239022
};

const signedJwt = jwt.sign(payload, {key: pkcs1PemEncrypted, passphrase: 'whatever'}, { algorithm: "RS256" });
console.log(signedJwt);

//
// Verifying
//

const spkiPem = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

const verifiedJwt = jwt.verify(signedJwt, spkiPem, {complete: true})
console.log(verifiedJwt.payload);
```

---

Note that in the above code, the public PEM encoded key in X.509/SPKI format is applied during verification.
Since the ssh-keygen statement exports the public key in OpenSSH format by default, a corresponding conversion is required, e.g. with (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76685865/9014097)):

```
ssh-keygen -f "<path to existing public OpenSSH key>" -e -m pkcs8 > "<path to X.509/SPKI key to be generated>"
```

Alternatively, the public key can be extracted from the private key (e.g. with ssh-keygen or OpenSSL).